# Redirigir Información de input a google maps

Tags: php, javascript, html5, google-maps, google-api

Muy buenas tardes, necesito saber si hay alguna forma se colocar la información que hay en el input y con el boton, lo redirija google maps con esa información y busque el resultado.

[image: foto]

Ya se que google maps tiene las api, y las he investigado, pero no entiendo como implementarlas a lo que yo necesito, el más cercano que encontré fue el places, pero aun así no lo entiendo
A continuacion les muestro o que tengo en codigo de esa foto

```
                    <div class="row form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4">Direccion:</label>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="direccionEditar" class="form-control" readonly>  
                    </div>

                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning fas fa-plane" href="https://www.google.cl/maps/preview" target="_blank"></a>
                </div>
```

No quiero implementar el mapa de google dentro del php, lo que quiero por ejemplo es que al tocar el boton, se abra una pestaña aparte con target:"_blank" y que se abra google maps, en el ejemplo anterior, tendria que redirigir a algo así:

[https://www.google.cl/maps/place/Av.+Vicuña+Mackenna+1231](https://www.google.cl/maps/place/Av.+Vicu%C3%B1a+Mackenna+1231)

Muchas gracias!

Comment: según los tags que colocaste, lo que quieres es implementar mapas a través de PHP?

Comment: No quiero implementar el mapa de google dentro del php, lo que quiero por ejemplo es que al tocar el boton, se abra una pestaña aparte con target:"_blank" y que se abra google maps, en el ejemplo anterior, tendria que redirigir a algo así: www.google.cl/maps/place/Av.+Vicuña+Mackenna+1231

Comment: Si quieres mostrar siempre la misma dirección, es simple, solo debes incorporar el mapa dentro de un nuevo template. Pero si lo que quieres es poder buscar direcciones a través de tu página y que te muestre el resultado en otra pestaña, necesitarás varias cosas: Primero, un framework que te permita consumir el api de google maps, google maps trabaja con coordenadas, así que necesitarás una dependencia que transforme tu dirección en latitud y longitud, y ya con eso puedes usar el template que te entrega google para implementar el mapa usando los parámetros que te entregue la dependencia.

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo esta solución.

Primero asignar un evento al botón de consultar.

```
    <a onclick="return mostrarLugar();" type="button" class="btn btn-warning fas fa-plane" href="https://www.google.cl/maps/preview" target="_blank"></a>
```

Despues obtienes el valor y simplemente abres una nueva pestaña con el método `open` que esta en el objeto `window`

Dicho esto tu código se vería así.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4">Direccion:</label>
    <div class="col-9">
        <input type="text" name="" value="Av.Vicuña Mackenna 1231" id="direccionEditar" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>

    <a onclick="return mostrarLugar();" 

    type="button" class="btn btn-warning fas fa-plane" 

    href="https://www.google.cl/maps/preview" target="_blank">Consultar</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function mostrarLugar(){
  let item = document.getElementById('direccionEditar')
  if(item){
    window.open('https://google.cl/maps/place/'+item.value, '_blank');
  }  
  return false; //No ejecutar el evento.
}
```